# setting up plnkr for angularjs pagination not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, plnkr.co

I am new to using plnkr. I have created my first plnkr and facing an issue in setting the `$scope.currentPage` variable. All other variables are working fine except the currentPage. I am using the `angular-utils-pagination` directive. 
Once I click on the page number the variable is getting printed but when the page gets loaded for the first time the variable is not initialized.
Please let me know where I am going wrong. The link for the plnkr - [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/L7pIg19JQVfGUIhu6ngF?p=preview)

Comment: For starters, you've created a controller , MyController, but never use it on any of your pages.  What is the purpose of the MyTable directive?  Do you plan on this being a reusable component in your app?  If not, I'd get rid of it and do everything in one view and one controller.

Comment: I updated the plnkr but getting weird error now which I am not able to debug. Please let me know where I am going wrong. Link - http://plnkr.co/edit/L7pIg19JQVfGUIhu6ngF?p=preview

Comment: Error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- myTableDirective
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20myTableDirective
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4289
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4437)
    at angular.js:4294
    at getService (angular.js:4437)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4469)
    at angular.js:7080
    at forEach (angular.js:336)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:7078)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are injecting $scope into your MyApp directive. There's no need to do this since directives have access to their parent scope by default. So it should look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myTable', function ()
```

Comment: Thanks. It really saved a lot of my time.